# SQL Server stored procedure get one column from last executed select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which select a few records from a table. Within the same stored procedure, I wish to execute an update statement referring to the primary key to the above executed select query.

As an example

```
create procedure myproc
as
begin
    select col1, col2, col3 
    from table

    update table 
    set col5 = value 
    where col1 = <value of col1 from above select query>
end
```

I have read about a solution of using subquery to get the column from last query but I am seeking a better way, if any

**Edit for more clarity**

```
 create table emp
(id int, name varchar(30),age int,status bit)

insert into emp values (1,'sam',23,null)
insert into emp values (2,'mike',33,null) 
insert into emp values (3,'marc',42,null) 



create procedure myproc as
begin
select top 1 id,name from emp where age>30 order by id --it will return row number 2 with id "2"
update emp set status='1' where id =2 -- "2" is the id we got as a result of above select query
end
```

i want to get the select query result as well as update to happen after select query

Comment: This is unclear. Your `SELECT` is going to return multiple rows, so with your `UPDATE` (which is referencing the same table) you to want to `UPDATE` the value of `col5` with multiple values of `col1` from the same table where a single value of `col1` has the value of every value in `col1`? That would be impossible and doesn't make sense. Sample data and expect results will likely better explain what you're *really* after.

Comment: @Larnu could you please help now

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to update some records and also get the data stored in the table BEFORE the update as a resultset of the stored procedure. (Or do you want both the previous and the new values?)

Comment: Please see the edit to get more clarity

Comment: @SachuMine Your edits are not consistent, which suggests me that either you don't have clear business requirements or you are unable to present them properly. Please tell us, what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update something and get the data stored in the table BEFORE the update, then you can use a simple `UPDATE` query with `OUTPUT`

```
WITH SRC AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
            id
        ,   name
        ,   status
    FROM
        emp
    WHERE
            age > 30
    ORDER BY
            id ASC
)
UPDATE
    SRC
SET
        SRC.status = 1
OUTPUT
        Deleted.id
    ,   Deleted.name
    ,   Deleted.status  AS StatusBefore -- status BEFORE the update
    ,   Inserted.status AS StatusAfter  -- status AFTER the update
;
```

**Sidenote**: This question was updated multiple times, this answer is based on the update where you've added the definition of the `emp` table and some vague implementation of your business logic ([revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58670268/6)).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
create procedure myproc
as
begin
    update table 
        set col5 = value 
        where col1 in (select col1 from table)
end;
```

Note that your original query has no filtering, so this is equivalent to:

```
   update table 
        set col5 = value 
        where col1 is not null;
```

However, if you specifically wanted both results, you could use a temporary table:

```
create procedure myproc
as
begin
    select col1, col2, col3 
    into #tempt
    from table;

    update table 
    set col5 = value 
    where col1 in (select col1 from #tempt)
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am seeking whether there is any other Most optimized way of getting it.

Comment: @SachuMine Why do you think, that this solution is less optimized?

Comment: because of 2 select statements

Comment: @SachuMine Query/SP performance is not measured in the number of select statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to subquery then you can join:

```
create procedure myproc
as
begin
    select col1, col2, col3 
    from table
    where 'some conditions'

    update t1 
    set col5 = value
    from table t1 
        inner join 
            (
                select col1
                    --obviusly you do not need this columns here..., col2, col3 
                from table
                where 'some conditions'
            )t2
        on t1.col1 = t2.col1
end
```